# (jquery) toggle() on an <span> with "position: absolute; display: inline;"

Tags: jquery

I have a form with input boxes horizontally across the page. I'm trying to use an inline span with "position: absolute" so that the validation error floats above the other form elements. For the below demo, I've reversed visibility so that the validation message hides on hover and appears on non-hover.

On the initial page load, the validation error appears on top of the other form elements correctly, all is well. Once you hover, causing a jquery toggle, the text hides, which it should, still all is well. But when you mouse off, causing another jquery toggle, in Chrome the validation text wraps down to the next line. In Firefox, the validation text randomly appears in the correct and incorrect spot as you mouse over and mouse off. It's crazy!

No, I don't want to use toggleClass, because that doesn't animate.
No, I don't want to use tooltip, I need to use a custom span.
I just want toggle() to put the element back where it started.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $( 'span.validationicon' ).hover(function(){ $(this).next().toggle('fast').css("display", "inline");});
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    <span>
        <label>Contact Number</label>
        <input type="tel"/>
        <span class="validationicon">!!!</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; display: inline;">Validation error goes in here</span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <label>Contact Name</label>
        <input type="text"/>
        <span class="validationicon">!!!</span>
        <span style="position: absolute; display: inline;">Other validation error goes in here</span>
    </span>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you reproduce the error in a jsfiddle?

Comment: No, it works fine in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xL46v9a6/